# Spring cloud gateway gives 500 error finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8083 when run with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, spring-cloud-gateway

```
enter code here
```

Hi! I have 2 different microservice and I am running them on docker with the help of docker compose I have spring cloud gateway through which I am supposed to fetch or connect other microservice the problem is the gateway is giving 500 error but  when I access api_1 through its designated port on docker like localhost:8083/Publish/message it gives message with out any hindrance,

This is the error I am getting when I am trying to connect gateway-service to api_1

> curl -v http://localhost:8081/Publish/message
> {"timestamp":"2021-04-19T12:57:27.400+0000","path":"/Publish/message","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8083"}

> or-http-epoll-5] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [d6036c7b] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/Publish/message"
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8083
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused

Here is my docker-compose.yml

> gateway-service:  
> image:cloudapi 
> port:"8081:8081"  
> depends_on:
> api_1  
> api_2  
> api_1:  
> image : publishimages:latest 
> ports:"8083:8081"  
> depends_on 
> gateway-service
> api_2:  
> image : mobileapi:latest 
> ports:"8084:8081"  
> depends_on  
> gateway-service

also tried to  use this instead of localhost

> http://[service_name]:[running_port]/

I tried an alternative as I figured like Each container is a separated host/machine I have to connect from the gateway host to service host still that error persisted and idk what is it that I am missing or doing wrong because I am really a newbie at docker and I don't know much about I have inspected the container they seems to fine

Comment: Don't forget that microservices call each other by container-name

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you're using Docker Desktop, I found deselecting the option Use Docker Compose V2 fixed my problems. Spent a long time working on reinstalling things. Definitely worth a try before doing anything big.